# State of ucblogo package in debian / raspbian

Tags: debian, apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian

My son and I are playing around with LOGO programming on a Raspberry Pi (in Raspbian). We ran into a problem with the current package (v 5.5) not properly interpreting arrow key input: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/arrow-keys-output-scancodes-in-ucblogo

The current version of UCBLogo, according to https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html, is 6.0 (released in late 2008).

Is there a reason that http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/u/ucblogo/ only has the 5.5 version? Can the package be updated to 6.0 from the source on https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Debian package tracker: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ucblogo.

The maintainer has stopped his work on this package ([orphaned in July 2015](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790725)).  There won't be no update unless someone takes over the maintenance.  For now you should probably build it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about tracker.debian.org. Is there a good community/resource available for helping me resolve specific build errors? I tried building from source last night, but ran into a few roadblocks.

Comment: @JacobCarpenter I have no idea about resources, but posting a question on the problem after some efforts of your own would always be welcomed here.  Good luck!